# How to compile LESS file(s) into CSS file in .NET

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less

I know how you can use dotless to have LESS file(s) compiled into CSS when bundling in an MVC app.  What I want to be able do, though, is control the LESS-to-CSS conversion in a C#/.NET application outside of the scope of bundling.  Is there a way to either define a destination location in the file system or retrieve a stream of the CSS file in code using Cassette.less?

Comment: You need to include the less.js library. http://lesscss.org/#download-options

Comment: I'm currently using Cassette.Less, available as a NuGet package. But unfortunately, questions asking for a tool are not in the scope of StackOverflow, and I'll have to vote to close.

Comment: Nice try! :P ... Cassette use dotLess internally, only makes easier to configure, bundle and cache your scripts. You can check how to [configure cassette here](http://getcassette.net/documentation/v1/stylesheets/less) or use only dotless, their have a 5-step configuration [on their main page](http://www.dotlesscss.org)

Comment: @Andre: This will allow me to compile LESS to CSS in code?  I specifically am trying to convert LESS files to CSS in a C# console app where bundling doesn't exist.

Comment: I wonder if the easiest thing is to just download `lessc` and invoke it via `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`...

Comment: @im1dermike dotLess allow you to compile using command `dotless.Compiler InputFileName.less OutputFileName.css`

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the dotless.Core.dll in your C# console app and than call `Less.Parse();`. The `Less.Parse();` only accepts code. If you will have to compile a file (with imports) you can use the dotless.Compiler command as suggested by @im1dermike.

See also: http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2010/11/setup-dotless-in-aspnet-project/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/features/less) to compile `LESS` into `CSS` for you.  You can then use the generated file for bundling.

If you wanted even more control over the process you could always create a grunt/gulp task to compile the `LESS`.

[Compile LESS files with Grunt](http://ericnish.io/blog/compile-less-files-with-grunt)